# how do i know if my cage is to small (syrian)

Tags: hamsters

i have a syrian hamster who looks to be 3-5 inchs. can you tell me what you think by looking at the picture below.[image]

Comment: what are the measurments of the bottom plate,knowing this will be helpfull in giving you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

That looks fine, hamsters do not naturally tend to roam much and a large space can often be a lot worse than a slightly smaller space. However could do with more enrichment, maybe some tubes